# How to get object automatically on form using source code at Delphi?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

```
procedure TMyForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  Group: TListGroup;
  Item: TListItem;
  s1, s2: string;
begin
  ListView1.ViewStyle := vsReport;
  ListView1.GroupView := True;
  ListView1.Columns.Add.Caption := 'My column';
  Group := ListView1.Groups.Add;
  Group.Header := 'My header';
  Group.GroupID := 0;
  Item := ListView1.Items.Add;
  Item.GroupID := 0;
  Item.Caption := 'My item';

end
```

I copy pasted above code on my RAD Embarcadeo delphi form code. But why I am not getting 
components automatically on the form after pasting above code at suitable place on CODE tab...
Instead it is giving many errors like

```
Undeclared identifier TListGroup at line 27 
Undeclared identifier TListItem at line 28
Undeclared identifier ListView1 at line 31
Undeclared identifier ViewStyle at line 31
Undeclared identifier vsReport at line 31
Undeclared identifier GroupView at line 32
Undeclared identifier TListGroup at line 27
```

Comment: What did you *expect* that code to do? I think you lack an understanding of what that code means, which of course raises the question of why you copied it in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

There is a `ListView1` component on your source form that you should also copy to your new form.  When viewing the code from the old form, press `F12` to toggle into form view.  Find and select the `ListView1` component, and copy it.  Paste it into the form view of your new form.  When you do that and save your new form/code, it will add the needed unit(s) to the `uses` clause of your new code.  That will fix your errors.